# GET http://localhost:8080/null 404 (Not Found) in RaspberryPI

Tags: javascript, python, html, linux, raspberry-pi

Im using RaspberryPI and USB camera to make mini raspberry pi project, but when click start Camera button in web, I got GET http://localhost:8080/null 404 (Not Found) error. Here are codes from my project, but I think one of delivery.html, mqttio.js, mqtt.py is wrong. I've really been looking at the code for over 6 hours, but I really don't know how to fix this. What should I do?

templates/delivery.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mini project</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.2/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./static/mqttio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./static/image.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
           window.addEventListener("load", function () {   
                var url = new String(document.location);
                ip = (url.split("//"))[1]; // ip = "224...:8080/"
                ip = (ip.split(":"))[0]; // ip = "224..."
                document.getElementById("broker").value = ip
           });
      </script>
    <style>
        canvas {background-color:lightblue}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <h3>camera</h3>
        <hr>
                <form id="connection-form">
                        <b>broker IP:</b>
                        <input id="broker" type="text" name="broker" value=""><br>
                        <b>port : 9001</b><br>
                        <input type="button" onclick="startConnect()" value="Connect">
                        <input type="button" onclick="startDisconnect()" value="Disconnect">
                </form>
        <hr>
    <h3>get image(topic:image)</h3>
         <hr>
         <form id="subscribe-form">
            <input type="button" onclick="startCamera()" value="start camera">
            <input type="button" onclick="stopCamera()" value="stop camera">
         </form>
         <canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
         <hr>
         <h3>Led (topic:led)</h3>
         <hr>
         <form id="LED-control-form">
            <label>on <input type="radio" name="led" value="1" onchange="publish('led', this.value)"></label>
            <label>off <input type="radio" name="led" value="0" checked onchange="publish('led', this.value)"><br><br></label>
         </form>
         <hr>
         <h3>get temperature(topic:temperature)</h3>
         <hr>
         <form id="subscribe-form">
            <input type="button" onclick="subscribe('temperature')" value="start">
            <input type="button" onclick="unsubscribe('temperature')" value="stop">
         </form>
         <h3>get distance(topic:ultrasonic)</h3>
         <hr>
         <form id="subscribe-form">
            <input type="button" onclick="subscribe('ultrasonic')" value="start">
            <input type="button" onclick="unsubscribe('ultrasonic')" value="stop">
         </form>
         <div id="messages"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

static/mqttio.js

```
var port = 9001
var client = null;

function startConnect() {
    clientID = "clientID-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100);


    broker = document.getElementById("broker").value;

    client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(broker, Number(port), clientID);

    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
    client.connect({
        onSuccess: onConnect,
    });
}

var isConnected = false;

function onConnect() {
    isConnected = true;
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>Connected</span><br/>';
}
var topicSave;
function subscribe(topic) {
    if(client == null) return;
    if(isConnected != true) {
        topicSave = topic;
        window.setTimeout("subscribe(topicSave)", 500);
        return
    }

    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>Subscribing to: ' + topic + '</span><br/>';
    client.subscribe(topic);
}

function publish(topic, msg) {
    if(client == null) return;
    client.send(topic, msg, 0, false);
}
function unsubscribe(topic) {
    if(client == null || isConnected != true) return;

    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>Unsubscribing to: ' + topic + '</span><br/>';

    client.unsubscribe(topic, null);
}

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>error</span><br/>';
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>error : ' + + responseObject.errorMessage + '</span><br/>';
    }
}


function onMessageArrived(msg) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived: " + msg.payloadString);

    if(msg.destinationName == "image") {
        console.log("received")
        drawImage(msg.payloadBytes);
    }

    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>topic : ' + msg.destinationName + '  | ' + msg.payloadString + '</span><br/>';
}

function startDisconnect() {
    client.disconnect(); 
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '<span>Disconnected</span><br/>';
}
```

mqtt.py

```
import io, time
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import camera
import base64
import temp
import circuit



isStart  = False

def on_connect(client, userdata, msg, rc):
        client.subscribe("camera")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        global isStart
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
                isStart = True
                print("Start Camera")
        else:
                isStart = False
        pass

def on_connect(client, userdata, flag, rc):
    client.subscribe("led", qos=0) 

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    on_off = int(msg.payload) 
    circuit.controlLED(on_off) 

broker_ip = "localhost"

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(broker_ip, 1883)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_start()


camera.init()
stream = io.BytesIO()

while True:
    if isStart == True:
        frame = camera.take_picture()
        stream.seek(0)
        image = Image.fromarray(frame)
        image.save(stream, format='JPEG')
        client.publish("image", stream.getvalue(), qos=0)
        stream.truncate()
    else:
        print("I am idle")
        time.sleep(1)

    distance = circuit.measure_distance()
    temperature = temp.get_temperature(temp.sensor)
    client.publish("ultrasonic", distance, qos=0)
    client.publish("temperature", temperature, qos=0)
    time.sleep(1)

camera.release()
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT']=0

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return render_template('delivery.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

circuitpy

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def controlLED(on_off):
    GPIO.output(led, on_off)

def measure_distance():
    GPIO.output(trig, 1) 
    GPIO.output(trig, 0) 

    while(GPIO.input(echo) == 0):
        pass

    pulse_start = time.time()
    while(GPIO.input(echo) == 1):
        pass
    
    pulse_end = time.time() 
    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start 
    return pulse_duration*340*100/2 

trig = 20 # GPIO20
echo = 16 # GPIO16
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(trig, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(echo, GPIO.IN) 

led = 6 # GPIO6
led = 5
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO6 
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO5
```

temp.py

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from adafruit_htu21d import HTU21D
import busio

def get_temperature(sensor):
    return float(sensor.temperature)

def get_humidity(sensor):
    return float(sensor.relative_humidity)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
sda = 2
scl = 3

i2c = busio.I2C(scl, sda)
sensor = HTU21D(i2c)

def read_sensor_data():
    while True:
        temperature = get_temperature(sensor)
        humidity = get_humidity(sensor)
        print("temperature is %4.1f" % temperature)
        print("humidity is %4.1f %%" % humidity)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_sensor_data()
```

camera.py

```
import sys
import time
import cv2
camera = None
def init(camera_id=0, width=640, height=480, buffer_size=1):
    global camera
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id, cv2.CAP_V4L)
    camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, buffer_size)

def take_picture(most_recent=False):
    global camera
    len = 0 if most_recent == False else camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE)
    while(len > 0):
        camera.grab()
        len -= 1
    success, image = camera.read()
    if not success:
        return None
        
    return image
def final():
    if camera != None:
        camera.release()
    camera = None
```

static/image.js

```
var canvas;
var context;
var img;


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
});

function bytes2base64( bytes ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( bytes );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}

function drawImage(bytes) {
        img.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + bytes2base64(bytes);
}

var isImageSubscribed = false;
function startCamera() {
        if(!isImageSubscribed) {
                subscribe('image');
                isImageSubscribed = true;
        }
        publish('camera', 'start');
        img.src = null
}
function stopCamera() {
        if(!isImageSubscribed) {
                unsubscribe('image');
                isImageSubscribed = true;
        }
        publish('camera', 'stop');
}
```

The code using led, ultrasonic sensor, and temperature sensor works fine, but only USB camera is a problem, so I looked at all the related codes, but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: `img.src = null` means that the image is being loaded from `/null` - relative to where the page is loaded (I assume that would be `http://localhost:8080` ... does your server respond to `/null` path?